# WiFi keeps disconnecting while using a Proxy

Tags: wireless, networking

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Acer Aspire One Netbook and everything works excellent except for the WiFi.

When I click on a network I get connected but only for about one minute and then it says "Disconnected - You are offline".

It tries to reconnect and after a while it says "Connection Established".

It's a school network which uses no authentication but a proxy (`172.16.4.1:8080`).

Can anyone help me? I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know a thing.

Comment: Driver issue probably?

Comment: I have exact same problem on my computer, my network even just "times out".
Have you checked if you have the latest drivers for your network-card? And yeah, on my computer, it only disconnects on the proxy-authenticated network, not on any other network. Is the same happening to you?

Comment: thing could be driver yeah, but most likely the network uses a lot of routers, right? (placed around on the school) And after what i experienced, ubuntu aren't handling multiple routers pretty well. The network incompatible with ubuntu in some way.

Comment: Could you please tell us which model is your wifi card? You can use the lspci command to get such information.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with your proxy server , please check your account with some other OS'. (Like a windows os or something like that)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to start by examining the proxy configuration?